# Is it possible to send/receive data to/from a SOAP web service from unmanaged C++/MFC code?

Tags: c++, web-services, soap

I have an C++/MFC project that I need to connect to a SOAP web service from to send data and receive a response. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tools that can help you do it, such as [gSOAP](http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/), which works basically as you would expect it too (similar to Java and .NET WSDL to code generators).

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. I'll look into it.

Comment: Hi again. I seem to be running into a problem with gSOAP. The wsdl file that I need to connect to uses the https protocol and the build of the wsdl2h.exe that comes in the package doesn't work with SSL. I tried to re-build the wsdl2h module with Visual Studio 2008 but I keep getting a ton of linker errors and it's way above me to fix it... (I'm sure I didn't do something right.) So I was curious, how do you deal with SSL wsdl sites?

Comment: I've never used gSOAP with SSL. Have you tried this: http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.24 (gSOAP SSL on Windows)?

Comment: Thanks, I tried linking to libssl.lib and libcrypto.lib but where do you get them from? Those files aren't in the gSOAP package...

Comment: I'm sorry, but this stuff drives me nuts... Now I need to compile another package to get those lib files. How do you do that?

Comment: Oh the joys of C/C++ development :). They have a link to [binary distributions for select operating systems](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html), of which Windows is one. You want version 1.0.0d, the latest release of OpenSSL. At this point, it might be easier to simply write a DLL in managed code (C# for instance) and interact with it like any other shared library, and use Interop from C# to provide access.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 7 and later you can use the Windows Web Services API

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430435(VS.85).aspx

which will work fine from a C++ application.

Martyn

Comment: Hah. Interesting. Thanks. Unfortunately I need this to run on Vista and possibly XP as well.